# Implementing UIPickerView delegates in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass that contains a `UIPickerView`. I'm trying to get the subclass to implement the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` interfaces rather than have the view controller that manages the table also manage the UIPickerView. (Once I get a cell I'd like to be able to send it a message to set the UIPickerView).

I thought this would be straightforward, but I'm missing something very basic. In my UITableViewCell subclass I try to set the delegate here:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    // NSLog() here never gets called
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
      _picker.delegate = self; // try to set delegate
    }
    return self;
}
```

But this never even gets called. Shouldn't this get called when the cell is created? `_picker` is a declared property connected to the UIPickerView on the Storyboard.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: if you are initializing your cell with this method of your custom cell class, only then this method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put initialization code in

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    // initialization stuff
}
```